# UIImagePickerController Picking More than one Image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

How can i Pick more than One Image from the UIImagePickerController?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can do that directly, through the API. But you can simply keep the picker open and build up a list of images in the callback:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    [images addObject:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
    // There has to be some exit condition,
    // otherwise the user would pick forever.
    if ([images count] == 3)
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```